Error while converting a .h5ad file into a Seurat object in R
I am trying to perform single cell RNA seq analysis and have a .h5ad file that I am trying to convert into a seurat object to start analysing it.
So far, I have converted the file into a h5seurat file. The problem I am facing is at the step when I try to load this h5seurat file.
This is the code I have written in R:
library(Seurat)
library(SeuratObject)

if (!requireNamespace("remotes", quietly = TRUE)) {
install.packages("remotes")
}

remotes::install_github("mojaveazure/seurat-disk", force = TRUE)

library(SeuratDisk)

#reading in the h5ad file
#STEP1: convert the annData object to h5Seurat object
Convert("file.h5ad", dest="h5seurat", overwrite=TRUE)

#STEP2:loading the h5Seurat file
file_seurat<- LoadH5Seurat("file.h5seurat")

When I run STEP2, this is the error message I get:
Error in fixupDN.if.valid(value, x@Dim) :    length of Dimnames[[1]] (28728) is not equal to Dim[1] (2219)
I am aware that this implies that there is a discrepancy between:
Dimnames[[1]] : which refers to the names assigned to the rows (usually the features) which has a lenght of 28,728.
Dim[1] : which refers to the actual number of rows in the data matrix and has a size of 2,219.
But I am not sure about what I would need to do to solve this issue. Appreciate all the help I can get!

On my part, your code works with the dataset provided here: https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/cellxgene/blob/main/example-dataset/pbmc3k.h5ad, can you check that this is also the case for you? If so it might be an issue in your dataset.
Maybe try opening it as a h5ad first with the package anndataR, and verify that the dimension are the ones that you expect?

Hi, so did try the code with the dataset pbmc.h5ad and my code worked!
Upon inspecting the .h5ad dataset I wished to work with this is what I get:
Data matrix shape: (195739, 2219)
Number of feature names: 2219
Number of cells: 195739

So you do have the correct number of feature names...
And anndataR function obj <- adata$to_Seurat()does not work neither on your dataset?

sorry for the delay in response, I did try this but I seem to be getting the same error. I do believe it has something to do with the original .h5ad file, so for now I have decided to use another file for my analysis. I shall keep you updated in case I do work a solution out for this! Thanks!
